# When session.flush() failed on SQLAlchemy, should I call rollback?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I know rollback called when `session.commit()` failed such as `try-except` block.
But when `session.flush()` failed, should I execute `rollback()`?

```
try:
    session.flush()
except IntegrityError:
    session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failed flush is always rolled back, you do not need to do it yourself:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush

*Database operations will be issued in the current transactional context and do not affect the state of the transaction, **unless an error occurs, in which case the entire transaction is rolled back**. You may flush() as often as you like within a transaction to move changes from Python to the database’s transaction buffer.*

Comment: If the session is not configured with autocommit=True, you absolutely *do* need to explicitly rollback your transaction after a failed flush, otherwise your session will be in an unusable state (the other answer here is correct).

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is not entirely correct. The documentation about `Session.flush()` is a bit misleading about this.

Upon failure, the transaction (i.e. the *database* transaction) will be rolled back (by the **database**). Its python counterpart, the `Session` object itself will then be in an "inactive" state and, according to the documentation [1](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/errors.html#this-session-s-transaction-has-been-rolled-back-due-to-a-previous-exception-during-flush) [2](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/sessions.html#faq-session-rollback)

> must be explicitly rolled back by the calling application, in the same way that it would otherwise need to be explicitly committed if a failure had not occurred.

It does further acknowledge that

> this is a common error when using the ORM

Comment: I just encountered this. If I understand correctly, `session.rollback` only affects the Python side. If the transaction flushed successfully, rollback will have no affect on the Database, and the object/row will still exist in it. For example if you flushed, but did not commit, a row you will generate `id=1`. Next time you flush the auto-increment will be 2, even though you rolled-back. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @barakbd When the session is flushed, it communicates to the db transaction what changes in the session must be applied inside the transaction. For instance, if new session objects are created and flushed, it instructs the db transaction to create new rows with new IDs. When the session is committed, it instructs the db transaction to commit the changes (and close the transaction). `session.rollback` also rolls back the db transaction. IDs are indeed not recycled across transactions.

Comment: This is why I create a single session, set autoflush=False, and only commit once al models are successfully populated. The ORM `relationship` removes the need for generating IDs for Foreign Keys during model instantiation.